# CSS pseudo element tooltip has the same width as the original element

Tags: html, css, tooltip

[Here i got the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/8dpt0p1h/1/)

```css
body {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color: #E5E2D9FF;
}

abbr {position: relative}

abbr:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFFD7;
  background-color: #0000009C;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Tooltips</h1>
 <h2>Simple tooltip</h2>
 <h3>With 'abbr' tag</h3>
 <p><abbr title="This is a simple tooltip">Lorem</abbr> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati ea quae iste, voluptates nihil nesciunt laboriosam saepe magnam, odio molestiae architecto! Reprehenderit exercitationem magnam, illo possimus vero ducimus, commodi magni!</p>
```

I want that the `:after` pseudo element's width is different from the original element.

Thanks :)

Comment: simply specify a width

Comment: yes, but I want the width to accommodate the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a width to pseudoelement.

```css
    body {
     padding: 5px 10px;
     background-color: #E5E2D9FF;
    }

    abbr {position: relative}

    abbr:hover:after {
      content: attr(title);
      position: absolute;
      color: #FFFFFFD7;
      background-color: #0000009C;
      padding: 2px 5px;
      bottom: 0; right: 0;
      transform: translate(100%, 100%);
      border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<h1>CSS Tooltips</h1>
<h2>Simple tooltip</h2>
<h3>With 'abbr' tag</h3>
<p><abbr title="This is a simple tooltip">Lorem</abbr> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati ea quae iste, voluptates nihil nesciunt laboriosam saepe magnam, odio molestiae architecto! Reprehenderit exercitationem magnam, illo possimus vero ducimus, commodi magni!</p>
```

Of course, you can set max/min-width, combine with non-width and `white-space: no-wrap` if you have just short texts with unknown width and want them on one line, etc.

Comment: yes, but I want the width to accommodate the content

Comment: @Saul: and where is the problem? Read properly what I wrote under the code snippet. Check the edited snippet now.