# How could I get the content of the elements by just using CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I first use CSS, I thought it is impossible to get the properties of an element. However, I found this code [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695771/css-pseudo-element-tooltip-has-the-same-width-as-the-original-element), it shows that I can get the properties of elements by using CSS.

For example, if I want to get the title of `<abbr>` element, I can just use this code:

```css
abbr::before{
  content:attr(title);
  color:red
}
```

```html
<abbr title="the title">
  Content Test
</abbr>
```

`attr(title)` give me the title of `<abbr>`

In that case, I want to ask if there is a way to get the content of the element.

For example, I want to get `Content Test` in the code in my example **by just using CSS**.

How could I finish that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS only get text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335753/css-only-get-text)

Comment: @toffler I do not think so, I found another [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text) in that question, and I tried to use *content:text(.class1);* and *content:text(#id1);*, but they both not working. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What you're looking for isn't possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the question. Why get the content of ? change style or change the content?
You can define content through CSS rather than through HTML. Maybe this will help you:

```css
abbr::after{
  content: 'Content Test';
  color:red
}
```

```html
<abbr title="the title">
  
</abbr>
```